# Custom filter in the sales order admin grid giving Invalid block t

Tags: adminhtml, magento-1, sales-order, order-grid

I've been able to filter custom added column  like 'seller name ' its get from seller id of product.

other filters are working.

```
$this->addColumn('seller_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Seller Names'),            
        'index' => 'seller_id',
        'filter'    => true, 
        'sortable'  => true,            
       // 'renderer'  => 'marketplace/adminhtml_productrequest_renderer_sellername'
    ));
```

when I try to use the column to search I get an error like this.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: 1' in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php:595
>       Stack trace:
>        C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>       1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance(true, Array)
>       2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php(369):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock(true)
>       3 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php(51):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getFilter()
>       4 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(314):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->setGrid(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid))
>       5 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Search\Grid.php(157):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->addColumn('seller_id', Array)
>       6 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(624):

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,your `Marketplace module name` is ***Abc_Marketplace***.

As per as magento,there `should be a class` exit in your module

***Abc_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Productrequest_Renderer_Sellername***
Which ***may be does not exit*** in your system `that reason it show error`.

**May class name is wrong or may path location is wrong.for those reason you got error.**

As per your comment,your block type prefix is mp.

> ```
> <blocks>
>       <mp><!-- this called as block type prefix  for Abc_Markeplace module -->
>           <class>Abc_Marketplace_Block</class>
>       </mp>
>       ...
>     </blocks>
> ```

So render class  block type is

***'renderer'  => 'mp/adminhtml_productrequest_renderer_sellername'***

Comment: Abc_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Productrequest_Renderer_Sellername is there in Adminhtml based on this class only I'm getting seller name.

Comment: Changed 'renderer'  => 'abc_marketplace/adminhtml_productrequest_renderer_sellername' showing fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object. ../Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php but when i've been changed 'filter'    => true,  to **false**  there is no error.

Comment: can you please show your marketplace config.xml code

Comment: this not config.xml code.. i asking about your marketplace etc/config.xml fi;r

Comment: its big file which part you need to change

Comment: `<blocks>....</blocks>`

Comment: <mp><class>Abc_Marketplace_Block</class></mp><page><rewrite><html_pager>Abc_Marketplace_Block_Html_Pager</html_pager>               </rewrite></page><checkout><rewrite>onepage_shipping_method_available>Abc_Marketplace_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available></rewrite></checkout><adminhtml><rewrite><catalog_product_edit_tabs>Abc_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Producttabs</catalog_product_edit_tabs></rewrite><catalog><rewrite>                        <product_list_toolbar>Abc_Marketplace_Block_Product_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar></rewrite></catalog></adminhtml>

Comment: Please check the answer